# Relationship between BufferedImage, Graphics, and Canvas for games

Tags: java, swing, canvas, 2d, game-development

I am a fairly new programmer and I am trying to make a very basic game using Java where you just move a sprite around the screen. What I have accomplished so far is make a SpriteSheet class that loads in my sprite sheet and saves a BufferedImage of the spritesheet as a field of that class and a Sprite class that will get a subimage(the sprite itself) from this field and saves it as a field in the Sprite class. I've tested this and it all works like it should. I understand this may not all be typical or the "correct", efficient way of doing things. I'm ok with figuring that out on my own but my problem now is understanding the relationship between BufferedImage, Graphics, and Canvas. I saw a tutorial where a guy saved his sprite as a BufferedImage and  used this to create a Graphic. He then painted this Graphic onto a Canvas and added the Canvas to his JFrame. He also fit a BufferStrategy in there somehow connected to his Graphics, and I don't understand that at all. Whenever I try to adapt his method for my purposes, it never works. I've looked over the javadocs countless times for these things and I get them individually, but I just can't seem to understand how they fit together to accomplish my goals.

**So in short**: can anyone explain how BufferedImage, Graphics, and Canvas all fit together in the context of displaying a sprite for a 2D game, and how is a BufferStrategy used? Appropriate and relevant methods? Will this method be appropriate for rendering moving sprites around 15 fps? etc... My problem does not come from a lack of research or lack of knlowedge necessarily but more from a lack of understanding.

Thank you very much and any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you should start by having a look at the [JavaDocs for `Canvas`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html), [`BufferStrategy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) and [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) for some examples

Comment: Oh, and generally speaking, this has less to do with Swing and more to do with AWT ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `BufferedImage` is a `Image` type, which has the capacity to be modified from within the code, but, it has no means by which it can paint it self to the screen.
- `Canvas` is a AWT (heavy weight) container which is typically used for providing activate painting access via it's `BufferStrategy`.  This is displayed to the screen.
- `Graphics` is a abstract graphical library designed to make it easier to perform cross platform renderering.

The `Canvas`, via it's `BufferStragegy` provides access to a `Graphics` instance, which allows you to paint to the `Canvas` (and by extension, the screen).  You use this `Graphics` context to paint the `BufferedImage`

A `Canvas` by itself can't be displayed on the screen, it must be first contained within a window of some type, like `java.awt.Frame`.

Essentially, the frame shows the user the `Canvas`, the `Canvas` provides access to the graphics hardware via the `BufferStrategy` and `Graphics` context and the `BufferedImage` provides a generalised representation of an image/image data which can be painted to the `Graphics` context (of the `Canvas`)

Maybe you should start by having a look at the [JavaDocs for `Canvas`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html), [`BufferStrategy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html), [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for some examples

Comment: Thanks Ill give those a look. That helps a lot. My main problem is trying to save my BufferedImage as a Graphics object.

Comment: [`Graphics#drawImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)), [2D Graphics, Drawing a Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html)...

Comment: So this is what I gathered: you create a Canvas. With that canvas you create a buffer strategy. From that buffer strategy, you can then create a graphics object. And then using that graphics object, you can draw your image using the drawImage method passing in my bufferedImage as an argument?